# Checking if a list item is contained in another list

Tags: python

I have not been able to figure out this problem, what i'm doing is, i have 2 lists this is one:

```
def allowed_links():
""" this function keeps a list email structures we are allowed to check ... """
    return ["registration.activate",
            "/activate/"]
```

And this is another:

```
        email_extract_urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', response[0][1].decode())

        if len(email_extract_urls) > 0:
            if allowed_links() in email_extract_urls:
                url_container.append(email_extract_urls)
```

The **url_container** is the other one, once the regex finds suitable urls they are added to the list.

My problem is i only want to add urls to the list that **contain** any of the words in the **allowed_links()** list.

I have not found a way to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `any()`:

```
for x in email_extract_urls:
    if any(y in x for y in allowed_links()):
        url_container.append(x)
```

Comment: Hello Austin, thank you for the help, when i test to urls are being added it seems, this is an example url structure: http://asite.com/en/component/users/?task=registration.activate&token=d224f27087491a1a22d16e18d6418c70 it contains **registration.activate** so we want to keep this one, is the code above checking the url if it contains **registration.activate** in it at all?

Comment: @tess, Yes. This takes each url from the output of regex and checks if any of the words in the list returned by `allowed_links()` is in the url and appends those.